# Make eclipse run testNG tests automatically on build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng

How to do it?

I could make an ant script but, as I understand, it won't show me the results in eclipse window.

Comment: Not sure, but I'd start by looking at project builders. In the properties of an eclipse project, you can define builders. Those can be defined to be triggered on certain events, such as builds.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what you want?  Eclipse does an incremental build every time a source file changes.  Do you really want to run all of your tests on every save?  Another possibility is to run a subset of tests on every save.  But, how do you choose what subset to run?  Infinitest may help somewhat in this situation, but I do not think it works with TestNG.

Comment: If I do it via eclipse builder mechanism, then I don't think I'll be able to see results in eclipse window. Since the project where I am going to use this is small, it won't take much resources to run tests on every build.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions on the TestNG site of [how to programmatically invoke TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically).  Of course you need to put your test code in a directory like  src/tests/com/test/mytests  , or something like that as a separate source tree in your project.  Then, your Ant script should be able to invoke it.

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();  
TestNG testng = new TestNG();  
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { 'tests/com/test/mytests/Run2.class' });  
testng.addListener(tla);  
testng.run();
```

I've not tried this myself and so your milage may vary on my advice.